# How do I get the index of current ui:fragment in a facelet?

Tags: jsf-2, facelets

```
<ui:fragment rendered="#{...}">
<p class="#{current.index eq 0 ? '' : 'someClass'}">
  Some Text
</p>
</ui:fragment>
.....
<ui:fragment ...>
<p class="#{current.index eq 0 ? '' : 'someClass'}">
  ...
</p>
....
</ui:fragment>
```

How do I get the index of current ui:fragment in the above facelet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're **hardcoding** them instead of using an iterating component like `<ui:repeat>` or so, so there's no index available in the scope. Just either hardcode the index as well, or use an iterating component like `<ui:repeat>` wherein the index is available by the `varStatus` reference.

```
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.list}" var="item" varStatus="loop">
    <p>#{loop.index}</p>
</ui:repeat>
```

Comment: I had to use jQuery to loop through all the classes to get the index for each element. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Depending on the functional requirement (which is unclear from the question) that can also be a solution, yes.

Comment: The functional requirement is to remove a css class depending on the condition I specified. There is no list to retrieve from the bean, if so your answer is absolutely right. As you said, they are hardcoded on the page as per the requirement.

Comment: You could utilize the CSS3 [`:nth-child(n)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3anth-child) or [`:first-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/:first-child) pseudoclass, maybe in combination with [Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/) to emulate CSS3 support in IE8 and older.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm using hardcoded text in the p tag,

```
<ui:fragment rendered="#{...}">
<p class="dummyClass someClass">
   Text 1
</p>
</ui:fragment>
<ui:fragment rendered="#{...}">
<p class="dummyClass someClass">
   Text 2
</p>
</ui:fragment>
.........
```

And then using jQuery

```
$('.dummyClass').each(function() {
    if($(this).index() == 1){
        $(this).removeClass('someClass');
    }
});
```

Note that the .index() with no parameters returns 1 for the first element.